# The page hangs when using location.href

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to make a transition to another page by clicking on the button, I tried with different pages, the transition to them worked, but the page I need hangs: location.href = http://localhost:3306/mountainBikes before pressing the button: [location.href = http://localhost:3306/mountainBikes before pressing the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxgYD.png)

location.href = http://localhost:3306/mountainBikes after clicking on the button: [location.href = http://localhost:3306/mountainBikes after clicking on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPSKh.png)

window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3306/basketForm' before pressing button: [window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3306/basketForm' before pressing button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kQxz.png)

window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3306/basketForm' after clicking on the button:[window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3306/basketForm' after clicking on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3uGH.png)

part of the server code that accepts the request /basketForm:

```
app.post('/basketForm', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    let html = 'public/basket.html';
    console.log(req.body);
    fs.readFile(html, (err, data) => {
        res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
})
```

part of the client code:

```
basketButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let output = '';
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = '/basketForm';
    for (let i = 0; i < bicycles.length; i += 2) {
        output += `Name=${bicycles[i]}&Count=${bicycles[i + 1]}&`;
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (request.status == 200 && request.readyState == 4) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3306/basketForm'
            },500);
        }
    }
    request.open('POST', url);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(output);
});
```

Comment: You can use [Barba.js](https://barba.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The page hangs because you are doing a `setTimeout` and it is loading a file.

Remove the `setTimeout`. The moment `request.status == 200` and `request.readyState == 4` occurs, it will be finished with its request.

Also, you should not be doing readFile in your route. Consider `sendFile` instead.

```js
app.post('/basketForm', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendFile(`public/basket.html`);
})
```

sendFile will pipe the file, meaning the moment it starts reading; its also sending that data out to the client. Right now you are waiting to send data until you have all of contents of `basket.html` when you could be starting to send much earlier if you just use `sendFile`.

Separate from this, I would highly recommend refactoring your code. What you are doing will work, but it's like the worst way you could do anything.

Consider using Cookies or LocalStorage to keep track of your basket, which I assume is essentially your "cart" on a shopping website.

Comment: Thank you. I try your solution later.

Comment: your solution didn't help me, but thank you